Why does the Voyager space craft use a 3.7 meter dish antenna?
I would like to know why the Voyager space craft used a 3.7 meter dish antenna to communicate with Earth.
Usually, the radius of a radio beam would increase as it goes farther away. How was this managed using that antenna in space? How is the size of such a dish antenna calculated?

Image source

Can you clarify what you mean by "the radius of a radio beam" and why you think it matters?

The dish is not expected to "catch" the whole "radio beam". It is expected to "catch" whatever is reaching it and focus it on the antenna.

Why do solar panels produce more electrical energy when there are more of them (a clue is the surface area)?

It was calculated to be the biggest one they could afford to launch :)

Ofosot, Just write (or call) the current team managing the project. This would be JPL and Dr. George Textor. Do not be shy. He will help you with any and all reasonable questions. It is a silly mistake to avoid asking the more knowledge sources. They will help you.

@periblepsis raises a good point -- there are educational opportunities here, and one could even write a whole series of essays -- or articles, or books -- or podcasts or videos, whatever medium you like -- documenting various technical aspects of the design. We have complete public records (though they may not be on-the-web public, but need NASA archive access) of the design, launch and service of this mission; and, indeed, the mission is still active, there is a small team working on it, quietly but enthusiastically :)

(Just FYI to anyone interested: There is a Space Exploration.SE site. They have a tag for the Voyager probes, as well as Q&A about their antenna like this one. I haven't researched to see if they have an answer to this specific question, but they might be another source of information now, or in future.)

@SamGibson I concur. Why was this migrated to electronicsSE, when space exploration is a better fit ?

@DavidHolzer :-)

I suspect, but I can't find any evidence, this is the maximum fixed dish that could fit the launch vehicle. They probably wanted larger.

I suspect this was migrated because it's also an antenna design problem, only peripherally (because of SWAP constraints) related to space.

Ofosot, I see that we still haven't so much as heard more than a peep from you since asking the question.  If you are still around, let us know. I've contacted JPL, by phone, today and left a contact message. Suzanne Dodd is the current project manager (sorry about the wrong name, earlier.)

@brhans beam of a radio is what you see a circle of light from a flash light when pointed to a wall or floor. Similarly, such a circle of radio wave is formed on the ground when any radio wave from a dish antenna hits the ground from space. If you bring your flash light closer to the wall, you will see the circle becoming smaller and brighter but when you move it away further, the circle gets bigger and dimmer. Similarly, any space craft sending a beam of radio signal to the ground would become weaker as it moves away. I just want to know know the size of the dish antenna on a space craft.

@Ofosot then you will need to read the answers you've already gotten, closely.

@Ofosot - Ok, but does your eye need to be as big as the circle on the wall for you to be able to see the light from the flashlight? No, obviously not. So similarly, why would the size of receiving dish antenna on the Voyager need to be in any way related to the radius of the radio beam it's receiving? You don't need to capture all of the light/radio in order to see/receive some of it.

In spacecraft (but generally, everywhere), decision on how big to make an antenna are trade-offs on a system-level, system being the whole spacecraft. Sure, the team building the comms link would have liked a much bigger disk – but that might have made it impossible to still launch the vehicle, or might  have been in the way of the scientific instruments, or would just have cost so much fuel to get into space that it would have killed the financial launch budget. Or any change of orientation would have needed so much fuel due to the additional hysteresis due to mass, that the mission wouldn't have worked out, because they would have ran out of fuel after the first planetary-aided acceleration.
On spacecraft, all components need to share the payload weight the rocket can get out of earth's gravity well, so, design of antennas becomes a process where the other teams need to weigh in (huhu, a pun!) and be heard.
As with any larger technical, there's always trade-offs to be made (the team designing your car's bumper would like that to be 1m thick, as well!), and the development process is iterative, where in a first round, everyone meets and discusses. Then, the different teams go to work, with an understanding of what specifications they need to write down. The power team writes down which things they'll take from others (mass and a place to put solar panels, supplies), and what they offer (power and stabilizing mass). Then the teams talk and negotiate: the on-board sensors team will ask for an amount of power and has specs for how much EM noise the supplies can cause (and that's not just "none at all", but actually a "we can work up to 98% of quality with this noise, and 99% with that noise"); the antenna team also needs the antenna to go somewhere and look in the same direction, and so on. They re-write the things: the antenna team negotiates that they get more power for their amplifiers and receiver chain (so they can use stronger transmit PA, and lower-noise receive LNA and better channel codes), and in exchange they can reduce the size of the antenna.
This goes on for months, in large space projects often years, then there's prototyping at component level, in-lab "unrolled" (flat) satellite prototypes, more iterating, and finally a testable spacecraft prototype that can be tested, and if reliable, launched.
So, your antenna size is the trade-off between desirable for communications, desirable for launch, desirable for science, desirable for power. There's not one formula, other than "get a lot of engineers into a room full of coffee, whiteboards and snacks, then give them time to work on the system, and please give them good project and program managers to coordinate efforts and solve conflicts".

And I don't think most people, even some engineers, appreciate how long it can take to go from concept to launch or deployment of a payload.  Last system I was intimately involved with took 18 years.  And there was some technology development going on before I came on board,  So maybe 20 years in all.

@SteveSh I'm currently involved with a "New Space" company, and it's astonishing at which speeds they go through development phases, whilst still having pretty stringent testing and reliability. It's twice as surprising, knowing ESA and DLR development processes secondhand / from ESA presentations, and having friends at classical satellite companies.

@Marcus Müller I expected a simple answer on how to calculate the size of a communication dish antenna.

@Ofosot and I wrote the answer that is correct: there is no such simple answer, sorry. You take as big as you can, but "as you can" is a whole-system engineering effort.

To a first order approximation, an antenna's sensitivity, that is how much power, or signal it can capture, is directly related to the size of the antenna or, more properly, the size of the aperture.
On the receive end of things, the energy impinging on the antenna is usually specified as a power density, as in uW per sq cm.  This is also specified in dB relative to a power level, as in -60 dBm.
So the way to capture more energy is to make the antenna/aperture bigger.  An antenna that's twice a big is going to capture twice the power, and so the sensitivity of the system will be twice as great (all other things being equal).
So for systems trying to detect very weak signals, you want the biggest antenna possible.  But like Marcus Muller pointed out, for many applications like spacecraft and airborn systems, the size of the antenna is constrained by things like size, weight, and power (SWAP) limitations.
According to this link, the size of the Voyager antenna was dictated by the largest antenna that would fit within the nose fairing the the rocket (without some complex deployment mechanism).
https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65801/what-are-the-parameters-of-the-voyager-high-gain-antenna
So while the Voyager spacecraft has a 3.7 m diameter antenna (for the reason Marcus mentioned), the other end of that communications link, the antennas of the Deep Space Network (DSN), have a diameter of 70 meters, making the antenna itself significantly more sensitive than the one on Voyager.

love the "slightly".

While the 70-meter ground antennas are significantly more sensitive than the Voyagers' 3.7 m antennas are in space, the transmitters in space is significantly weaker than the transmitters on the ground. The whole system was designed and built to work together. See DESCANSO Design and Performance Summary Series Article 4: Voyager Telecommunications and How to calculate data rate of Voyager 1? for the gory S/N details

[+1] for the actual answer: "nose fairing" :-) (also see  this answer to Why doesn't thermal radio emission from a DSN "hot dish" completely swamp the benefits of a cold LNA? and Did any of Voyagers' receivers' front ends take advantage of the "cold of space" to lower noise? (communications or radio/plasma science receivers))

So, what is t he formula or method for calculating the size of a two-way communication dish for a space craft?

It's not that simple.  You have to take into account the entire RF link, what's called the link budget.  This includes transmit power levels, transmit antenna gain, path loss, receiving antenna gain, receiver gain, noise figure, data rate needed, etc.  You can make up for lower gain on the receive side, for example, by increasing your transmit power.  Or by reducing your data rate.  You have to at all aspects of the problem; not the antenna in isolation.

@SteveSh I got that but what I need to know is how the size 3.7 m was calculated? What is the method of calculating any communication dish antenna on a space craft?

you really didn't read either Steve's nor my answer, @Ofosot, if you're still asking "what's the formula". We literally tell you. It's in our answers already: You take "bigger if possible". Also, not a cool move to ask the same question as a different user on physics.SE.

@Ofsot - The diameter wasn't calculated. It was a fallout given all the other constraints the designers had to work with, the main one being the size of the fairing on the launch vehicle.

And once that size was determined, the gain of the antenna falls out directly for a given frequency/wavelength.
